# Camera not working on Macbook Pro

Tags: webcam, macbook-pro

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Macbook Pro, everything works fine except the camera does not work/ is not found. Both Google Hangouts and the Cheese application say "no device found".

Anything I can install to get it working?

Comment: Do you use some virtualization platform?

Comment: No I completely wiped over the Mac OS, so solo Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Try this solution https://blog.jbfavre.org/2016/03/03/Linux-Driver-Webcam-FacetimeHD-Apple-MacBook-Pro/ For obvious reasons, I can't test it by myself.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, the command "git clone debian" says "debian is not a repository".

Comment: Instead of `git clone debian` try `git clone https://github.com/jbfavre/bcwc_pcie.git -b debian --single-branch`

Comment: @M.Dm. please delete your comment and propose as answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As at 8/3/2020 follow the instructions [Here](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#devvideo-not-created). They come in two parts, make sure you also follow the ones for your platform. They are a bit jumbled on the site so I have included them below.

I'm running 18.04 LTS (Bionic) on a 2013 Macbook Pro. The instructions that worked for me were as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
**add line "facetimehd", write out (ctl+o) & close**
```

Most of those steps will need to be repeated every time the kernel is upgraded.

I also followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Extracting-the-sensor-calibration-files) prior to testing the colors of the camera.

Comment: on 18.04, I had to install `xz-utils` instead of `xzcat` as the latter was not found. Otherwise perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I got this error on the "make" command:Checking dependencies for driver download...
/usr/bin/xzcat
/bin/cpio
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'AppleCameraInterface' failed
make: *** [AppleCameraInterface] Error 1

Comment: I'm not sure and I'm not about to replicate the error but [this](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/issues/41) has some ideas. Also `xz-utils` might work instead of `xzcat`. As I said this is what worked for might and there may be variations between different Mac models.

Comment: "patjak"'s source code is just the way we like it. Simple. Sober. Efficient. Reliable. A project I'd happily donate to (if there was a donate button).

Comment: I had the following issue upon running the second `sudo make install`: `certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory`. I solved it using [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322832/318883).

Comment: I get this error at the make install stage for bcwc_pcie unfortunately:
:~/bcwc_pcie$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-123-generic/build M=/home/MYHOME/bcwc_pcie modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-123-generic'
  INSTALL /home/MYHOME/bcwc_pcie/facetimehd.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory

Comment: @funkypitt - see my comment above.

Comment: If you want these changes to persist after kernel update you need to setup dkms according to these instructions:
https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#setting-up-dkms-auto-compile-on-kernal-update-1

Comment: incase you run into this error: make: *** [Makefile:36: AppleCameraInterface] Error 1.  try: sudo apt-get install curl.  because the script checks "which curl" and without manual install curl it returns nothing.

Comment: This works, even on jammy / 22.04. Note `xzcat` is in `xz-utils` package now. I had it in base desktop install.

Answer (score 17):

I followed the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@racter/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-retina-macbook-11-2-74e7779c0e47)(under the section "webcam drivers") and it is working now.

```
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie/firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

Comment: After I shutdown my laptop, when I next turned it on, camera no longer works again.

Comment: just add `facetimehd` to your /etc/modules file.

Comment: Maybe I should replace `$ sudo install` into `$ sudo make install`?

Comment: It's generally not an awesome idea to run `make` as root.  Security isn't as huge of a deal as some might say, since a malicious script could just as easily be malicious during "make install".  But you end up with a bunch of root-owned files in that directory, even though the git clone was run as non-root.  That can be annoying later.

Comment: @dannysauer if you don't you may run into this error `mv: cannot stat 'System/Library/Extensions/AppleCameraInterface.kext/Contents/MacOS/AppleCameraInterface': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @trendsetter37 That mv command happens after a curl piped through cpio.  If you get that error, it's a result of failing to download or extract a file.  Most likely, either there's an Internet issue, or you did the git clone as root and created a repository structure that you can't write to.  IMO, the path should not be `/etc/local/src` to begin with, but I assume that's why someone would run the clone as a user other than themselves.  Edit to remove the initial `cd /etc` pending. :)

Comment: Yea, I actually used `/opt/src` as a personal preference and ran into a similar issue. Also you instructions above do not seem to work for Ubuntu 18.04 on the Macbook Pro 14,3 model fyi @dannysauer

Comment: I see why. During the `sudo make install` step it's copying into a non-existent folder `Copying firmware into '//lib/firmware/facetimehd'`

Comment: The `/lib/firmware` directory is created on my Ubuntu 18.04 system by a number of packages, including linux-firmware.  But even if it didn't exist, the `install` command should create any necessary parent directories because of the `-D` argument.  I'm not sure what's broken for you, @trendsetter37 (I use OpenSUSE on my macbook), but keep digging. :)

Comment: the second make install command gave me an error saying a folder didn't exist ....but .... it worked. Camera working perfectly now.

Comment: Thank you for this! I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Macbook pro A1398 early 2013 model and your answer fixed the camera problem.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for selected answer.
Below is *modified* version for what worked as at Dec 11, 2021 here's what worked for me on Ubuntu 21.10

```
sudo apt-get install git curl cpio kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
**add line "facetimehd", write out (ctl+o) & close**
```

Comment: ??? `sudo modprobe facetimehd
modprobe: FATAL: Module facetimehd not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-39-generic`

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me on a macbook pro mid 2014 ubuntu 22.04 lts thanks!