# Camera not working on Macbook Pro. Previous solutions don't work for 20.04

Tags: 20.04, macbook, macbook-pro, camera

This is the error message on 20.04 when trying to follow the instructions: These instructions on [Camera not working on Macbook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990218/camera-not-working-on-macbook-pro)

```
/etc/local/src/bcwc_pcie/firmware/facetimehd-firmware/facetimehd-firmware$ make

Checking dependencies for driver download...
/usr/bin/xzcat
/usr/bin/cpio
make: *** [Makefile:36: AppleCameraInterface] Error 1
```

How do I fix this on 20.04?

Comment: Apologies, this was meant to be 19.10. I am following the recipe given here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/990218/camera-not-working-on-macbook-pro# which makes the macbook pro camera visible in Ubuntu. This is particularly useful nowadays as I am working from home and need the camera. Sadly the recipe does not work anymore with Focal Fossa

Comment: Try [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231411/1025264). I helped another person get there camera working