# Camera not working with Ubuntu, solution's stopped working (FacetimeHD, Macbook Air)

Tags: webcam, macbook, macbook-air

I've got a Macbook Air with Ubuntu installed, and I've had trouble in the past with my camera. I used patjak's solution from [this forum thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990218/camera-not-working-on-macbook-pro), which I'll reiterate below.

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
**add line "facetimehd", write out (ctl+o) & close**
```

Now, this has worked for a while-- I've had to re-enter the code a few times after an update, but it worked afterwards. However, now it's officially not working anymore. I think the issue is after the `sudo modprobe facetimehd` step, where I'm getting this output:
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'facetimehd': Exec format error`

I'll be completely honest, I know practically nothing about coding (I know, "Then why are you using ubuntu," haha), so sorry if I sound like an utter newbie-- I am. Anyway, any idea what I ought to do next?

Comment: I think you'd better contact Patrik Jakobsson, who wrote the software you're building. You could do that by raising an [issue](https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware/issues).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'facetimehd': Exec format error" after upgrading.  Making 'clean' before making facetime-firmware and bcwc_pcie fixed it for me.  Although, you shouldn't have to do this if you are downloading a fresh copy of of the source code into an empty directory.

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make clean
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
**add line "facetimehd", write out (ctl+o) & close**
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! For now, anyhow. Thanks so much!